# integrate auth0 in a web app express / node js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, auth0

I'm trying to add auth0 to my web app, I've followed their tutorials and other tutorials on the web, including creating account/client and everything else, but I keep getting the usual white page loading screen and after several minutes I receive this error:

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

These are parts of my code:

*app.js*

```
...
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
...
// Configure Passport to use Auth0
var strategy = new Auth0Strategy(
 {
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: process.env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) => {
  return done(null, profile);
  }
 );

passport.use(strategy);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
 done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
 done(null, user);
});
...
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session(
    {
     secret: uuid(),
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: false
    }
  )
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
...
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/home', routes.home);
...
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port: ' + app.get('port'));
});
module.exports = app;
```

*index.js*

```
exports.home = function(req, res){
 res.render('home', { title: ' homepage ' });
};

exports.index = function(req, res){
 var express = require('express');
 var passport = require('passport');
 var router = express.Router();

var env = {
  AUTH0_CLIENT_ID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  AUTH0_DOMAIN: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL: process.env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL 
};

// GET home page. 
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home', { title: ' homepage ' });
});

// Perform the login
router.get(
  '/login',
  passport.authenticate('auth0', {
    clientID: env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    domain: env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    redirectUri: env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL,
    audience: 'https://' + env.AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/userinfo',
    responseType: 'code',
    scope: 'openid'
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);

// Perform session logout and redirect to homepage
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

// Perform the final stage of authentication and redirect to '/home'
router.get(
  '/callback',
  passport.authenticate('auth0', {
    failureRedirect: '/'
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/home');
  }
);
}
```

There are some parts that are not clear to me or on which I would like to have a confirmation:
1) the callback URL must be my homepage (180.180.180.180/home) or the real first page (180.180.180.180)? Which one should be included in the auth0 dashboard?

2) In the router, should I also specify the / login and / logout fields or should these be managed directly by the auth0 API?

Sorry for my ignorance but it's days I have this problem, I do not understand if it's an authorization error with the auth0 account or something else.
I have the credentials in a .env file, but they should not be the problem, as I can access other data in them to connect to my MySQL database.

Comment: env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID. Do you get this from local variable right? Did you set it up yet?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's all in my .env file.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of auth0 `The callback URL is not necessarily the same URL to which you want users redirected after authentication.`

```
redirect_uri field is used as a callback URL. Auth0 invokes callback URLs after the authentication process and are where your application gets routed.
```

You can redirect the user to a non callback URL after authenticating the user and storing the same url in web storage.
On app.get(/login)...>authenticated>>landing page>>stores the access tokens
So post authentication it should login to your landing page (home).

On app.get(/logout), you can clear the access tokens or make it available for desired time and let it get expired after certain time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will keep this in mind but this does not solve my main problem for login. Do you know something about it?

Comment: Use a third party auth0 provider like passport to avoid writing everything from scratch and stumbling upon uneasy errors.Please find this link:https://github.com/auth0/passport-auth0. You can refer the example codes and format your own as an alternative. I use github /passport strategy. Find the link here (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm only interested in using auth0 for work and its integration with very efficient android systems. For passport-auth0 I'm already using it.

Comment: Is this the only error you are getting ?As I can see you are not handling CORS in your app.js file. Is it related to that x-access control error?

Comment: Yes, this is the strange thing, I only receive this error after a while 'time that the browser tries to load my login page. After a few days, I asked them directly, but I still have not received any answers. Excuse me but I'm pretty new about it and I've never heard of CORS, do you think it depends on this? are not enough auth0 credentials and packages to allow the exchange of information?

Comment: In modern browsers like Chrome some resources outside the routing end points are not accessible if CORS is not enabled.You can use these two lines "var cors = require('cors');app.use(cors());" in your code.Or you can use an extension (ex:moesif CORS) to turn on/off CORS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, added CORS but nothing change. If can help I receive this in pm2 monit: *app > GET / - - ms --*, and browser continues to display: *waiting for a reply from MY_DOMAIN* and after few minutes display white page with this message: *page doesn't work MY_DOMAIN was not found data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE*.

Comment: Just in case can you see your authenticated audience in here?: https://manage.auth0.com/#/apis

Comment: Yes, I can see my *Auth0 Management API - API SYSTEM*,I do not know if it can help but if I try to view my public API in the browser, I receive the following error message: *{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}*